# Desert Wind Rage

Tags: dnd-4e

Desert Wind Rage's passive effect is that you deal 5 + Strength modifier damage to all enemies within 5 squares at the start of each of my turns.  If I have the feat Deadly Rage (Player's Handbook 2) and/or the utility power Strength of Enduring Pain (Primal Power), will their increases to damage effect the Desert Wind Rage aura?

I.e., 5 + Strength modifier (6) + Deadly Rage (2) + Strength from Enduring Pain (10) = 23 damage to all enemies within 5 squares.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, Desert Wind Rage's passive effect does not benefit from damage boosters**

From PHB2, pg184 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Deadly Rage**
>
> Benefit: You gain a +1 bonus to *damage rolls* while raging. ...

From PP, pg18 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Strength of Enduring Pain**
>
> Effect: Until the end of your turn, you gain a bonus to *damage rolls* equal to the ongoing damage...

Both give a bonus to damage **rolls**. Desert Wind Rage's passive effect does not roll damage: 5 + Str is a static value. Thus, Desert Wind Rage's passive effect does *not* benefit from Deadly Rage or Strength of Enduring Pain (or almost any other damage boosters; pretty much all of them increase damage rolls).